# Can't figure out how CBLAS works

Tags: c, octave, blas, openblas

I trying to use cblas.h (from openblas library) to compute the product of two matrices.
Μore specifically, Ι have a double array A, with dimensions n*d, an array B with dimensions m*d and an array C with dimensions n*m. I want to compute the product A '*times*' B transpose.

My code is

```
#include <cblas.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void random_matrix(double *X, int rows, int cols);
void print_matrix(double *X, int rows, int cols);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  int n = atoi(argv[1]),
      m = atoi(argv[2]),
      d = atoi(argv[3]);

  double *A, *B, *C;
  A = malloc(n*d*sizeof(double));
  B = malloc(m*d*sizeof(double));
  C = malloc(n*m*sizeof(double));

  random_matrix(A,n,d);
  print_matrix(A,n,d);

  random_matrix(B,m,d);
  print_matrix(B,m,d);

  cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor,
              CblasNoTrans, CblasTrans, n,m,d,
              1.0, A, n, B, m,
              0.0, C, n
            );

  print_matrix(C,n,m);


  return 0;
}

void random_matrix(double *X, int rows, int cols){
  for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
      X[i*cols+j] = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX + (double)(rand()%10);
}


void print_matrix(double *X, int rows, int cols){
  for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      printf("%g ", X[i*cols+j]);
    }printf(";\n");
  }printf("\n\n");
}
```

When I run the program with n = 6, m = 5 and d = 2,
the output is:

```
9.00001 8.75561 ;
2.53277 8.04704 ;
9.6793 5.3835 ;
2.83097 3.05346 ;
9.67115 2.38342 ;
9.41749 7.58898 ;


3.84617 8.09196 ;
5.416 6.91032 ;
7.26245 3.73608 ;
9.63264 1.99104 ;
2.24704 6.72266 ;


105.466 117.964 4.58702e-309 4.70574e-309 0 ;
-1.83255e-06 35.5969 39.9896 1.59969e-309 1.4802e-309 ;
0 -1.83255e-06 0 0 0 ;
0 0 -1.83255e-06 0 0 ;
0 0 0 -1.83255e-06 0 ;
0 0 0 0 -1.83255e-06 ;
```

Which is wrong because when I try it on octave,
I get:

```
octave:52> A = [9.00001 8.75561 ;
> 2.53277 8.04704 ;
> 9.6793 5.3835 ;
> 2.83097 3.05346 ;
> 9.67115 2.38342 ;
> 9.41749 7.58898 ;];

octave:53> B = [3.84617 8.09196 ;
> 5.416 6.91032 ;
> 7.26245 3.73608 ;
> 9.63264 1.99104 ;
> 2.24704 6.72266 ;];

octave:54> A*B'
ans =

   105.466   109.248    98.074   104.127    79.084
    74.858    69.325    48.459    40.419    59.789
    80.791    89.625    90.409   103.956    57.941
    35.597    36.433    31.968    33.349    26.889
    56.483    68.849    79.141    97.904    37.754
    97.631   103.447    96.747   105.825    72.180
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it has to do with the leading dimensions `lda`, `ldb` and `ldc`.
The matrix A is stored as an array `A = malloc(n*d*sizeof(double))`.
When you use column-major access, the element A_ij is `A[j*lda + i]`.
Instead when you use row-major the A_ij is `A[i*lda + j]`

So in row-major, the `lda` is the number of columns of `A`. Respectively for `B` and `C`.

In conclusion, you must write:

```
cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor,
              CblasNoTrans, CblasTrans, n,m,d,
              1.0, A, d, B, d,
              0.0, C, m
            );
```